# Display number in adaptive card

Tags: adaptive-cards

I have the following simple card:

```
    {
        "type": "AdaptiveCard",
        "version": "1.0",
        "body": [
            {
                "type": "TextBlock",
                "text": "{data}"
            }
        ],
        "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json"
    }
```

When I apply the following data to the card (value is number), the text box is empty:

```
{
"data":11111
}
```

With text, the I can see the data in the card:

```
{
"data":"11111"
}
```

This is not a code issue, this is how it looks in the designer. Am I missing something, is there a type for a text box that lets display numbers or is this by design and I have to change all numeric fields to text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a limitation of the preview (known as Type Coercion) that we hope to address before release. As another workaround you can include a space after the binding expression which will force it into a string. See the below example, notice the space after `{data}`

```
   {
        "type": "AdaptiveCard",
        "version": "1.0",
        "body": [
            {
                "type": "TextBlock",
                "text": "{data} "
            }
        ],
        "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're using [Adaptive Cards Templating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/templating/) for this. Remember, this is (a) in preview only and (b) just **one** option for constructing an Adaptive Card. Basically, at the end of the day, the Card is just a string of JSON text so you can create it in 3 main ways:

1. Using Templates, as you're doing now
2. Doing string replacement of your own (e.g. var card = '..."text": "##Number##"...' and then card = card.Replace("##Number##", formattedNumberValue)
3. Using strongly-typed options like the [AdaptiveCards Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AdaptiveCards/) package for C#, for instance

So, I'd suggest, if this is not possible using Templating, to look more at options 2 or 3 above. I described this a bit more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59542964/how-to-convert-custom-json-to-adaptive-card-json-format/59544467#59544467), with some links to C# and Node examples.

Hope that helps

Comment: Well, right now, I am only building the card with designer at https://adaptivecards.io/designer/ so, I guess, that is using templating behind the scenes.

Comment: Ahh ok, I see. Yeah, seems to be a restriction in the new Templating, but if you start using it in an actual project you could use one of the other approaches I suggested, even if it's just in the interim till Templates gets to V1.

Answer (score 0):

You can now use the function `formatNumber(value, decimalplaces)`

Eg:

```json
{
  "type": "TextBlock",
  "text": "${formatNumber(somenumber), 2}"
}
```

You can read mode here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/adaptive-expressions/adaptive-expressions-prebuilt-functions?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#formatNumber