# Dynamic data Binding in Adaptive cards

Tags: adaptive-cards

I am looking for a way where I can bind the dropdowns used in adaptive cards with the data that I will get from my API.
Anyone know how to use https get calls in adaptive cards to prefill data.

Thanks

Comment: This feature is on the backlog but not scheduled yet. You should feel free to "vote" on the feature and add any comments you need which will help us prioritize it https://portal.productboard.com/adaptivecards/1-adaptive-cards-features/c/15-dynamic-searchable-select-menu-like-select2

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you can't do -inside- the card itself (i.e. from the user's bot client), but it's easy enough to dynamically create the card -before- you send it to the user. There are 3 ways I know of to do this:

1) you can compose the json string for the card yourself, and build up the dynamic options
2) you can using a strongly-typed library to create the card, and build the options dynamically in code (e.g. if you're using C#, you can use this [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AdaptiveCards/).
3) you can look at the new adaptive card templating (currently in preview).

I discuss these options more over here: [Display number in adaptive card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59662677/display-number-in-adaptive-card/59663953#59663953)