# How do dynamically bind data to adaptive card?

Tags: c#, .net, bots, adaptive-cards

I have created a bot using c#.net. I am fetching data from the SharePoint list and it will fetch a number of rows. The number of rows is dynamic. I want to add data in a Table format when the bot will answer in Teams. I want to use adaptive cards for showing data in a table format, but how do I bind that data in an adaptive card as the number of rows will change according to question asked to bot?
How can I bind data to cad dynamically in c#.net  bot code?

Comment: Are you trying to use [Adaptive Card templating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/templating/)?

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Answer (score 0):

This is no problem at all, you can simply build up the adaptive cards server-side (i.e. in your bot) with the amount of rows. It's possible to either construct the JSON for the adaptive card as a string (using stringbuilder) or, as you're using C#, you can using the strongly typed AdaptiveCards nuget package and do it all in C#, something like:

```
            var items = new System.Collections.Generic.List<AdaptiveElement>();
            for (int i = 0; i < whatever.count; i++)
            {
                items.Add(new AdaptiveTextBlock()
                {
                    Text = $"Item {i}",
                });
            }

            card.Body.Add(
                new AdaptiveContainer()
                {
                    Items = items
                }
            );
```

I discuss this more in this answer: [How to convert custom json to adaptive card json format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59542964/how-to-convert-custom-json-to-adaptive-card-json-format/59544467#59544467)

Comment: my requirement is that retrieving Sharepoint column values and that data should be bind with a card? how can I bind that data with template JSON of card?

Comment: Are you using Templating? If so, I can't help as I've not played with it, certainly not in terms of looping like this. It's in preview anyway though, so you could create your card in C# like above for now, and possibly change it to Templating later (or just leave as is)

Comment: I followed this link https://blog.botframework.com/2017/06/07/adaptive-card-dotnet/  to create an adaptive card, how can I create a card in c#, can u show some code

Comment: there's an example in that link, it's just much further down the page - search for "private static AdaptiveCard GetCard(string place)". It definitely shows how to do it, but there's lots of calling into sub methods - if you card is simple you can do it just in a one slightly longer method.

Comment: Can you add some info about the file structure? I'm also trying to do this, but I don't know how the file structure works and how a card can reference dynamic data in a project. All the samples I've seen show code but nothing about file structure