# Passing parameter to adaptative cards - MS Teams

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

How can I send a text as parameter to an adaptative card?
I'd like make the text (*Title - parameter*) dynamic, how can I send this value as a parameter?

That's the adaptative card content:

```
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.4",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "**Title - parameter**",
            "wrap": true,
            "weight": "Bolder"
        },
        {
            "type": "Image",
            "url":"urlIMage"
        },
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Text here",
            "wrap": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: The Adaptive Card Templating SDKs make it easy to populate a card template with real data on any supported platform. Please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/templating/sdk) which explains how to add dynamic data into Adaptive Card. Also refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59542964/how-to-convert-custom-json-to-adaptive-card-json-format/59544467#59544467) thread which explains thoroughly on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

As @Prasad-MSFT answeared me, using SDK solved my problem!